# Sequence contains no matching element. Error in '/' Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is my Entities Class calling:

```
public static Type GetJobItemType(string name)
{
    var result = _JobItemTypes.GetOrAdd(name, x => typeof(JobItemExt).Assembly.GetTypes().Single(y => y.Name == x && typeof(JobItemExt).IsAssignableFrom(y)));
    return result;
}
```

This is where it is called

```
job.Items = multi.Read().Select((p) =>
                {
                    var result = Activator.CreateInstance(JobItemExt.GetJobItemType(p.JobItemTypeName)) as JobItemExt;
                    result.Id = p.Id;
                    result.TenantId = p.TenantId;
                    result.Quantity = p.Quantity;
                    result.ParentId = p.ParentId;
                    result.PaintCost = p.PaintCost;
                    result.ModifiedDate = p.ModifiedDate;
                    result.ModifiedBy = p.ModifiedBy;
                    result.LaborCost = p.LaborCost;
                    result.JobItemTypeName = p.JobItemTypeName;
                    result.JobId = p.JobId;
                    result.DisplayText = p.DisplayText;
                    result.CreatedDate = p.CreatedDate;
                    result.CreatedBy = p.CreatedBy;
                    return result;
                }).ToList();
```

This is the stacktrace I am getting

> Source File: d:\saha progs\CodeProject_New\dev\CuttingEdgePainting.Entities\JobItems\JobItemExt.cs    Line: 89 
>   Stack Trace: 
>   [InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element]
>      System.Linq.Enumerable.Single(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) +2535897
>      CuttingEdgePainting.Entities.JobItems.JobItemExt.b__0(String x) in d:\saha progs\CodeProject_New\dev\CuttingEdgePainting.Entities\JobItems\JobItemExt.cs:89
>      System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) +72
>      CuttingEdgePainting.Entities.JobItems.JobItemExt.GetJobItemType(String name) in d:\saha progs\CodeProject_New\dev\CuttingEdgePainting.Entities\JobItems\JobItemExt.cs:89
>      CuttingEdgePainting.Services.DataServices.JobServiceExt.b__2c(Object p) in d:\saha progs\CodeProject_New\dev\CuttingEdgePainting.Services\DataServices\JobServiceExt.cs:182
>      System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +145
>      System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +381
>      System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
>      CuttingEdgePainting.Services.DataServices.JobServiceExt.GetJob(Int32 id) in d:\saha progs\CodeProject_New\dev\CuttingEdgePainting.Services\DataServices\JobServiceExt.cs:180
>      CuttingEdgePainting.ExteriorNew.Controllers.Mobile.JobController.Edit(Int32 id) in d:\saha progs\CodeProject_New\dev\CuttingEdgePainting.ExteriorNew\Controllers\Model\JobController.cs:91
>      lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +161
>      System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +59
>      System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +435
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +60
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod() +76
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +36
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3c() +117
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass45.b__3e() +323
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass30.b__2f(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass28.b__19() +72
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1e.b__1b(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9629708
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

When debugged I get the error on field name `c_DisplayClass17` (which I do not have in the dictionary also)

Where is it getting referenced? I am using MVC 3 Entity 4.5

Comment: Please learn how to format your questions.

Comment: My WTF meter broke reading your code. http://www.osnews.com/story/19266/WTFs_m

Answer (score 2):

The error you get is because you are using [`Enumerable.Single`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb535118(v=vs.100).aspx) with an expression that doesn't match any values in the enumeration. From the documentation:

> **InvalidOperationException**
> *No element satisfies the condition in predicate.*
> -or-
> *More than one element satisfies the condition in predicate.*
> -or-
> *The source sequence is empty.*

You can either handle that error or instead use [`Enumerable.SingleOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342451(v=vs.100).aspx) which will simply return `null` when no matches are found.

Comment: On Using SingleOrDefault, this error pops up The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type)' and 'System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.ActivationContext)'